# Jquery mobile popup is being reopened in wrong position on page resizing or scrolling

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, mobile, popup

In PC browser there is a problem that popup changes its position on window resizing. I googled it and found that JMF has a bug changing positionTo from origin/#codeSource to window.

In mobile browser I have the same issue on page scrolling. Popup is rendered again in wrong position.

I need either to set somehow correct position or to avoid multitime reopening on window resizing and page scrolling.

Could somebody give me a piece of advice?

Comment: Which jQM version are you using?

Comment: You want to re-position it to _window_ whenever it opens?

Comment: @Omar, no, I'd like to put it top,right, but when I do it, it works ones, but then it jumps to the center on page scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to `popupbeforeposition` event and alter `ui` object which that event omits. The object holds three *properties* which define popup's position, `ui.x`, `ui.y` and `ui.positionTo`.

The default value of the latter *property* is `window`, and it overrides any previously added values to `ui.x` and `ui.y`. Hence, whenever `popupafterposition` fires, `ui.positionTo` should be changed to `null` instead of `window`.

**Edit:** The below code should be wrapped in `pageinit` event <sup>(2)</sup>.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
  $("#popup_ID").on("popupbeforeposition", function (e, ui) {
      ui.x = value; /* (1) */
      ui.y = value; 
      ui.positionTo = null; /* this */
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2eCAV/)**

<sup>(1)</sup> value = number

<sup>(2)</sup> `pageinit` is a special jQM event which is equivalent to `.ready()` and should be used instead of it.

Comment: Thank you, I see that it works in jsfiddle, but my function on popupbeforeposition is called just one time. Looking for a reason...

Comment: @Tetyana can you update your question with your code?