# jQuery Mobile Popup keeps repositioning itself on scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I want to show a dialog on a jQuery mobile website such that:

- It displays when the page loads
- It shows the page behind it
- It should be dismissible by clicking outside it

I decided to use [jQuery mobile popup](https://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/) as follows:

- Create a `<div data-role="popup">` inside the *page*
- Programmatically open the popup on `pageshow` event of the *page*

It does the job just fine. **However, on mobile devices the popup moves around when the user scrolls the page**. Upon scrolling, the popup would disappear for fraction of a second, then reappear at a different position, possibly trying to stay inside the viewport. This behavior is undesirable.

The code I am using is this:

https://gist.github.com/salmanarshad2000/4b84e00f061508780e82e5a7b61d617b

To view the gist in mobile browser:

https://gitcdn.link/repo/salmanarshad2000/4b84e00f061508780e82e5a7b61d617b/raw/demo.html

The expected behavior:

- The popup opens at the top of the page, maintaining some gap on top, left and right
- When the user scrolls the page, the popup scrolls with it
- When the user stops scrolling, the popup remains where it was

Comment: An old answer that might shed some light https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732089/jquery-mobile-popup-is-being-reopened-in-wrong-position-on-page-resizing-or-scro/21778032#21778032 replace pageinit with pagecreate.

Comment: Looking at your code, the pageshow should go after loading jqm.js.

Comment: @omar in the actual production code it is placed after jqm.js

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the popup is repositioning itself on resize and on orientationchange, so I believe something is happening during the scroll mentioned in Your question, maybe it is due to a feature of the mobile device.

If You don't need that whole stuff, You can completely shut down the popup behaviour:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.widget("mobile.popup", $.mobile.popup, {
        _handleWindowResize: $.noop
    });
});
```

Be aware, this is a quick & dirty solution. The JQM team did a great job and spent a lot of time to test many different mobile devices, so my solution won't cover all cases - maybe it works just for Your requirements.

---

A note aside: the reposition in the middle of the window is a well-known bug. To adjust this, You may need to set the `data-position-to` attribute (or the `positionTo` option) and patch the `_resizeTimeout` function:

```
//this.reposition( { positionTo: "window" } );    
this.reposition( { positionTo: this.options.positionTo } );
```

Comment: I tried `data-position-to` but it did not work, may be I did it wrong or may be it was broken. Should I try again... like may be position to `body` element and somehow align it with top-center instead of middle (the docs say that jQM will position it in the middle of reference element which is absurd). Basically I want the popup to scroll with the page and not stay in the middle of viewport.

Comment: @SalmanA: did You solved this?

Comment: no, I have given up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from being an expert but I've tried to patch the method _handleWindowResize() of jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js by commenting off one condition among those that hide the popup.
It seems to work fine until now :

```
if ( ( /* this._expectResizeEvent() || */ this._orientationchangeInProgress ) &&
                !this._ui.container.hasClass( "ui-popup-hidden" ) ) {
...
```

**I'm not sure that does not produce issues elsewhere... :(**